# How to use map() function on multiple columns

Tags: r

I have got a data frame which looks like this:

```
x1   x2   x3     x4   ...
56   45   34    76    ...
56+3 56   42    43    ...
38   53   56-1  55+3  ...
...   ...   ...  ...   ...
```

In each row in more than 30 columns I want to keep only first 2 characters, so basically I want to remove all this "+3", "-1" etc. So in the end I will have:

```
x1   x2   x3     x4   ...
56   45   34    76    ...
56   56   42    43    ...
38   53   56    55    ...
...   ...   ...  ...   ...
```

I used below code to make such change in a single column, but I would like to be able to implement it on multiple columns at once. In the end as you can see I need to make each column a factor.

```
A <- substr(data$x1, start = 1, stop = 2)
data$x1 <- as.factor(A)
```

I thought about using map function from purrr but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub` to remove those characters by matching the `+` or `-` followed by digits (`\\d+`) till the end (`$`) of the string, convert to `numeric` and assign the output back to the original dataset

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(sub("[+-]\\d+$", "", x)))
df
#  x1 x2 x3 x4
#1 56 45 34 76
#2 56 56 42 43
#3 38 53 56 55
```

---

With `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    mutate_all(funs(as.numeric(str_remove(., "[+-]\\d+$"))))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(x1 = c("56", "56+3", "38"), x2 = c(45L, 56L, 53L
), x3 = c("34", "42", "56-1"), x4 = c("76", "43", "55+3")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expression solution and `apply`, we can return from each cell a group of anything followed by a `+` or `-`, followed by any number of digits.

```
apply(df,c(1,2),function(x) gsub('(.*)[+-]\\d+','\\1',x))

      x1   x2   x3   x4  
[1,] "56" "45" "34" "76"
[2,] "56" "56" "42" "43"
[3,] "38" "53" "56" "55"
```

Using `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
#map_df(df,~gsub('(.*)[+-]\\d+','\\1',.x))
df %>% map_df(.,~gsub('(.*)[+-]\\d+','\\1',.x)) %>%
       mutate_at(vars(starts_with("x")),as.factor)  #Change any var start with x to factor

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  x1    x2    x3    x4   
 <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct>
1 56    45    34    76   
2 56    56    42    43   
3 38    53    56    55
```

## data

```
df <- read.table(text = "
             x1   x2   x3     x4  
             56   45   34    76    
             56+3 56   42    43    
             38   53   56-1  55+3
",header=T)
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @akrun's answer, but with `str_extract`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate_all(~ as.numeric(str_extract(., "^\\d+")))
```

or simply the following if output not required to be numeric:

```
df %>%
  mutate_all(str_extract, "^\\d+")
```

**Result:**

```
  x1 x2 x3 x4
1 56 45 34 76
2 56 56 42 43
3 38 53 56 55
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(x1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("38", 
"56", "56+3"), class = "factor"), x2 = c(45L, 56L, 53L), x3 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("34", 
"42", "56-1"), class = "factor"), x4 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L
), .Label = c("43", "55+3", "76"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("x1", 
"x2", "x3", "x4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub` to only capture the first two characters, ie `(^.{2}).*` or even `(^..).*` then replace everything with the captured group, ie `\\1`. Now this creates a character matrix:

```
sub("(^.{2}).*","\\1",as.matrix(df))
     x1   x2   x3   x4  
[1,] "56" "45" "34" "76"
[2,] "56" "56" "42" "43"
[3,] "38" "53" "56" "55"
```

what you now need is to make all these as numeric while maintaining the dimension, we thus invoke either `array(...,dim(df))` or `structure(...,.Dim = dim(df))` then convert to `data.frame()`

```
data.frame(array(as.numeric(sub("(^.{2}).*","\\1",as.matrix(df))),dim(df)))
  X1 X2 X3 X4
1 56 45 34 76
2 56 56 42 43
3 38 53 56 55
```

Answer (score 0):

`readr::parse_num` will extract the fist number it finds, ignore the rest, and convert to numeric. We use it with `dplyr::mutate_all` so we'll attach `tidyverse` which will attach both `readr` and `dplyr` :

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate_all(parse_number)
#   x1 x2 x3 x4
# 1 56 45 34 76
# 2 56 56 42 43
# 3 38 53 56 55
```